# C++ Setting Values of a Private Array

Tags: c++, arrays, private

I'm creating Yahtzee in c++. The dice roll a number and depending on what number they roll, a position is created by subtracting 1 from randNum(since array is zero based). Then using that position I want to increment the appropriate element in my array to signify that I have rolled that certain number. For example: Dice roll 1,1,1,5,6,4. My array should show: 3,0,0,1,1,1. With my current code the elements are not incrementing. Any help is appreciated.

header:

```
class dice {
public:
    dice();
    void rollDice();
    int getRoll(int diceNumber);

    //This is the array that tells us how many of one number we have
    //ex) element 4 belongs to the #5 so if there is a 3 stored in element 4 that means we rolled 3 5's
    int arrayOfEachNumberRolled[5]{0,0,0,0,0};

    ~dice();
}
```

source:

```
void dice::rollDice(){
    //roll a random number and store it in the appropriate location
    int randNum;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){

        //Get the new random number between 1 & 6
        randNum = rand() % 6 + 1;
        //set the appropriate dice
        if(i == 0){//dice1
            dice1->set(randNum);
            arrayOfEachNumberRolled[randNum - 1]+=1;
        }
        else if(i == 1){//dice 2
            dice2->set(randNum);
            arrayOfEachNumberRolled[randNum - 1]++;
        }
        else if(i == 2){//dice 3
            dice3->set(randNum);
            arrayOfEachNumberRolled[randNum - 1]++;
        }
        else if(i == 3){//dice 4
            dice4->set(randNum);
            arrayOfEachNumberRolled[randNum - 1]++;
        }
        else if(i == 4){//dice 5
            dice5->set(randNum);
            arrayOfEachNumberRolled[randNum - 1]++;
        }
        else if (i == 5){//dice 6
            dice6->set(randNum);
            arrayOfEachNumberRolled[randNum - 1]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an array of 6 elements, not 5. Change

```
int arrayOfEachNumberRolled[5]{0,0,0,0,0};
```

to

```
int arrayOfEachNumberRolled[6]{0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

Comment: Facepalm emoji. Can't believe I missed that. Worked perfect. TY

Comment: @MattCucco, don't feel bad. Most of us have been there :)